# RDLC Report Parameter value is missing

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc

I am trying to pass a parameter from a code behind file to a RDLC Report. I have the same exact name "PayableAmount" in RDLC report paramters. If I set a default value it shows me that default value. Otherwise it shows me that PayableAmount parameter is missing value. I have searched a lot but unable to get it working.

```
            ReportHelper report = new ReportHelper();
            report.LoadReport(ReportType.Credit);
            ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[1];
            parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("PayableAmount", "34325");
            report.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
            report.ImportDataSet(GridList.ResultList.ToList(), "CreditItems");
            report.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Here is the parameter settings:

[image: Here is the parameter settings]

Here is the Set Parameter Values:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

can't add a comment so I have to put this in the answers but what is the datatype of your parameter and is it marked to allow blank value?

Comment: DataType is Text and allow blank value is not marked.

Comment: It shouldn't give you an error message if you check the allow blank value.  If I'm understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: Yes it won't give me error when I check the allow blank value. But I need that value, So that I can display it in the report.

Comment: Im not sure I'm following.  If you put a value in the parameter is shows but if you leave it blank it error.  Then if you check the box it won't error but you want the value to display still?  What value?  What ever value you put in the parameter in the code behind is what is going to display on the report?  What you are referring to as the default value is the way you set the value so what ever property you are using to get the info from the data set you need to put in the parameter where the 34325 is and it will pass it to the report.

Answer (score 0):

Check any value of any property is missing and null/empty value is not allowed for that property.

Comment: I have added another image to show value of parameter. Can you have a look?

Comment: what are other attributes? mention all attributes and their values

Comment: Which one are you talking about?

Comment: the value "34325" was not set properly.

Comment: It is set in values

Comment: Its just below ValidValues. Count is 1 and the value is set to "34325"